# How to use DOMXPath in C# for web scraping

Tags: c#, domxpath

Is there any way to use DOMXPath in C# like PHP for web scraping?  Or is there any alternative way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it is an HTML parser and supports querying using XPath.

Comment: @qmaruf - The download has a bunch of sample projects.